# How can I insert list elements into URLs

Tags: python, json, list, api, format

I’m trying to make API requests. It is to get stock prices and volume from Tiingo API, a data provider for algorithmic trading. In the below example it is looking for latest prices/volumes for ticker AAPL and SPY. I was wondering if there is a way in python that I can insert strings from a list into the url.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
requestResponse = requests.get(
    "https://api.tiingo.com/iex/?tickers=aapl,spy&token=APIKEY", headers=headers)
print(requestResponse.json())
```

Say I have a list of tickers:

```
tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AA-W', 'AAAB']
```

I want to put them in the url quotation in the following format(small caps and separated by comma after 'tickers='):

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
requestResponse = requests.get(
    "https://api.tiingo.com/iex/?tickers=a,aa,aa-w,aaab&token=APIKEY", headers=headers)
print(requestResponse.json())
```

Since I want to input many tickers, it is not very feasible to type them all in, so above is an example. I've tried the python format, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your list of tickers you can use `str.join` to create a string to add to your query

```
>>> tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AA-W', 'AAAB']
>>> 'https://api.tiingo.com/iex/?tickers={}&token=APIKEY'.format(','.join(tickers))
'https://api.tiingo.com/iex/?tickers=A,AA,AA-W,AAAB&token=APIKEY'
```

So to make your `get` query

```
requestResponse = requests.get(
    'https://api.tiingo.com/iex/?tickers={}&token=APIKEY'.format(','.join(tickers)), headers=headers)
```

If they must be lowercase you can do that with a generator expression within your `str.join`

```
>>> ','.join(s.lower() for s in tickers)
'a,aa,aa-w,aaab'
```